# Анимация смены контента при скролле

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let scrollDistance = window.scrollY;

  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.section1').forEach((el, i) => {
      if (el.offsetTop - document.querySelector('.nav').clientHeight <= scrollDistance) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.nav a').forEach((el) => {
          if (el.classList.contains('active', 'fadeInLeft', 'animated')) {
            el.classList.remove('active', 'fadeInLeft', 'animated');
          }
        });

        document.querySelectorAll('.nav li')[i].querySelector('a').classList.add('active', 'fadeInLeft', 'animated');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  padding: 100px;
}

.block-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

.section-left {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  /* background: gray; */
  width: 100%;
}

.section-right {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: red;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  /*     padding: 20px;
*/
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  display: flex !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black !important;
  display: inline-block;
  /*     margin-right: 25px !important;
 */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}

.subtitle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.content1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.fadeInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  animation-name: fadeInLeft;
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <div class="block-2">
    <div class="section-left">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>

          <li>
            <a href="" class="active subtitle">
              <div class="content1">
                <h1>O1</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content2">
                <h1>O2</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content3">
                <h1>O3</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="" class="subtitle">
              <div class="content4">
                <h1>O4</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>



        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="section-right">
      <div class="section1 wrap">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1 ">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap section1">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Есть небольшой скрипт, который при скролле должен меняет контент. Я применял его раньше для подсветки пунктов бокового меню при сколле, но решил применить для этой задачи. Не уверен, что он подходит для этого, но задачу он свою выполняет и ничего подходящего и простого на чистом js в инете не нашёл.
Но кроме смены контента, я хотел навесить ещё дополнительный эффект (.fadeInLeft, .animated) при помощи того же скрипта добавляя кроме .active ещё .fadeInLeft, .animated. Почти всё получилось). Но эффект начинает срабатывать постоянно при скролле не достигнув .section1 следующего элемента. Я не знаю, пошёл ли я правильным путём, но хотелось как-то попроще.
Прошу помочь разобраться знатоков js.

Comment: Вы же сначала удаляете все эти классы, а потом тут же их снова назначаете. И так при каждом скролле.

Comment: Но класс .active добавляется и срабатывает на позицию .section1 как надо, а эффект почему то нет. Вот я и хотел бы понять в чём проблема

Comment: проблема в том, что у вас при каждом скролле удаляются и навешиваются эти классы. Напишите где-то console.log и офигейте - сотни вызовов за одно пролистывание страницы. Я так вижу, что никто Вам не помог. Сейчас думаю найду время и напишу свой скриптик. Ваш подход по сути не верен. Результат похож на требуемый, но это грубо говоря совпадение. если таких скриптов будет на сайте несколько, то Вы уже будете не далеки от того, чтобы вкладка или браузер просто падали)

Comment: Еще с чего я проорался - пролистайте, например, до секции с <h1>02</h1>, нажмите исходный код этого элемента и увидите, что браузер думает, будто это секция с <h1>04</h1>. И это касается не только 02, но вообще всех секций.

Comment: Реакцию скролла видно даже просто в инспекторе (при каждом скролле добавляется класс .active). Для меня это тоже был вопрос - почему так? Значит проблема всё таки дело в скриппте, как я изначально и думал и просил помочь разобраться.

Comment: "Почему так" - потому что Ваш алгоритм такой: как только происходит скролл, мы удаляеем ВСЕ классы .active, а затем снова навешиваем нужному элементу. По сути, Вам нужно лишь проверять необходимость удалить .active и навесить нужному элементу, а не делать это каждый раз

Comment: Уточните, правильно ли я понял суть задачи: Справа есть несколько блоков произвольной высоты, как только один из блоков касается верхней границы окна, мы должны отобразить для него слева соответствущий блок с контентом?

Comment: Да. Правильно...